# "Overriding WordPress globals is prohibited" though the code seems alright

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php foreach ( $upsells as $upsell ) : ?>

            <?php
                $post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );

                setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

        ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

This yields

```
ERROR   Overriding WordPress globals is prohibited on line setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
```

I am working on a theme for thmeforest.net

Comment: Why you need this line : `setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); `

Comment: for to show upshell product in woocommerce plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong practice.You should use a wp_query to that product.

```
  add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_cross_sell_in_single_product', 30); 

function show_cross_sell_in_single_product(){
        $crosssells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids',true);
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'post__in' => $crosssells 
            );
        $products = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $products->have_posts() ) : 
            echo '<div class="cross-sells"><h2>Cross-Sells Products</h2>';
            woocommerce_product_loop_start();
            while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile; // end of the loop.
            woocommerce_product_loop_end();
            echo '</div>';
        endif;
        wp_reset_query(); }
```

Code Explaination : all upsell product are added using this function when you just write do_action() its simple.

Comment: did you get what I mean?

Comment: thanks, but codes has explained about  setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );  and has passed post as a global variable.